# Intimate sexual activity as a possible mechanism for transferring COVID-19

Tags: covid-19, oral-health, anus, oral-sex

New York City's Department of Health has issued a warning against performing rim jobs on other people, saying that it might be a means of transferring the COVID-19 virus to others:

> Rimming (mouth on anus) might spread COVID-19. Virus in feces may
>   enter your mouth,” the city warned in the section titled, “Take care
>   during sex.

Here's the link to the full article:

https://nypost.com/2020/03/24/nyc-declares-war-on-rim-jobs-in-graphic-health-department-memo/

This is the first time I've heard this:  We've been told, for a number of weeks now, that transmission of the disease is from touching our face with our hands.

Is the NYC Dept. of Health statement based in reality?

Should we stop performing rim jobs at the moment, in order to stop the spread of COVID-19?

Comment: "We've been told, for a number of weeks now, that transmission of the disease is from touching our face with our hands." - if this is all you've heard you haven't been listening...

Comment: See Graham Chiu's answer of this [question](https://medicalsciences.stackexchange.com/questions/21741/would-symptoms-differ-from-eating-virus-contaminated-food-versus-breathing-in-vi). Specifically "..it is thought that the faecal-oral route is also an important mode of transmission."

Comment: If you have an intimate physical relationship with someone then you're going to contract COVID-19 from them long before you get to their anus unless you have prior immunity. Kissing, touching, even just being face to face with them is going to transmit the virus.

Comment: This would be much more fitting on Skeptics SE.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best data we have from Guangdong, China, is that household transmission is not 100%

> preliminary studies ongoing in Guangdong estimate the secondary attack rate in households ranges from 3-10%.

So, this suggests that if either of you are potentially infected, then social distancing and other infection control measures will likely prevent the transmission from one to the other.

If, on the other hand, you have all been tested to be infection free (PCR or other reliable test), and you are in isolation without the risk of catching the infection from someone else, then as adults what you do in the privacy of your own homes is only limited by local laws and imagination.

https://www.who.int/docs/default-source/coronaviruse/who-china-joint-mission-on-covid-19-final-report.pdf